# ERROR 2003(HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'local.****.com' (110)

Tags: mysql, iptables

I am continually getting the error in the title when trying to do a mysql dump as per below:

```
mysql -hlocal.xxxx.com -uxxx -pxxx xxx < xxx.sql
```

Looking around, I thought it may have been an iptable issue but I've since allowed the designated address of local.****.com to the iptable, it says:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination          ACCEPT     all  --  local.*****.com    anywhere
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination

but am still getting the same error/issue. If anyone has some insight on what I could/should do to go about this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: what are the other ways you connect outside of command line ? Or should I also ask, when you connect via command line with above without <xxx.sql you get in right?

Comment: do you administer this server or is it remote and out of your control?

Comment: it's remote - I was able to connect to the remote server though with my public ssh key so I think that parts been done right? also @Ugo or anyone else if you can edit the name out from hlocal that'd be great!

Comment: you still can connect via ssh right? Anyway, I assume it is a rights issue. can you get in and do a `select user,host from mysql.user  order by 1,2`

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your help! I'm not sure what I did differently but it went through this morning fine without errors it seems.

Comment: awesome good luck Elisa